# Document Previews with Windows API Code Pack

Tags: c#

I am looking to obtain the file preview provided in Windows 7 through the Windows API Code Pack,

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

It was straightforward to obtain the thumbnail for the file, but can the preview of the file also be found through the API Code Pack?  I found some documentation on creating a preview provider...

I found the thumbnail (image of the file type) with:

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile);
Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```

Comment: Note, I don't think this is in the API Code Pack but I think its something that should be.  Could someone suggest a way to add this ability?  I'm new to the Windows API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many nasty details involved to get IPreviewHandler wrapped cleanly.  Shockingly, it is actually mentioned in the SDK article for the interface:

> Preview handlers can be built in
>   managed code. Typically, all preview
>   handlers are hosted together in a
>   surrogate process called prevhost.exe.
>   There is one instance of this process
>   for preview handlers running at normal
>   integrity level, and another instance
>   for preview handlers running at low
>   integrity level. If you want to
>   implement your handler in managed
>   code, your handler should not run
>   inside either of these shared
>   processes. Instead, arrange for your
>   handler to get a new instance of
>   prevhost.exe by creating a new AppID
>   entry in the registry (specifying
>   prevhost.exe as the DllSurrogate
>   value) and then setting that as the
>   AppID value in the registry value for
>   your handler's class ID. This will
>   ensure that a unique prevhost.exe
>   instance is created for your handler,
>   instead of the common instances used
>   by the other handlers.

This is the usual headache with shell interfaces, too much pomp and circumstance to get them going. The interface isn't wrapped in the code pack, I don't see how it could be wrapped cleanly with this required registry whacking.  Maybe you can google something from the interface name.  Codeproject.com usually has something.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I've been looking for a way to generate the document previews, do you have any suggestions?